# using require and backbone to load templates via html file and not script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I have a very simple web page which is using backbone simply to load a view from a template file:

```
<div id="content"></div>

<script src="js/vendor/json2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/flight-match-form.js"></script>
    <script type="text/template" id="template-flight-match">
      <section id="form-search" class="content-inner clearfix">
        <div id="date-container" class="search-row clearfix">
          <label class="search-label" for="date">Travel Date</label>
          <img src="images/structure/icon-calendar.png" alt="calendar" class="calendar">
          <span class="help-text" id="date-unknown">don't know it?</span>
        </div>
        <div id="flight-container" class="search-row clearfix">
          <label class="search-label" for="date">FLIGHT #</label>
          <input type="text" class="search-input" id="input-flight" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+">
          <span class="help-text" id="date-unknown">don't know it?</span>
        </div>
        <button id="button-match">
          Match
          <img src="images/structure/icon-arrow.png" height="15" width="20" alt="Submit Arrow">
        </button>
      </section>
    </script>
```

and in flight-match-form.js, I simply say:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var MatchView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function(){
            this.render();
        },
        render: function(){
            // Compile the template using underscore
            var template = _.template( $("#template-flight-match").html(), {} );
            // Load the compiled HTML into the Backbone "el"
            this.$el.html( template );
        }
    });

    var matchView = new MatchView({ el: $("#content") });

});
```

This works great, and all I really wanted to do next was to get all that html out of a script tag and into a proper HTML file, where I think it belongs. So, does anyone know the simplest way to do this?

I tried to follow [this tutorial](http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/), and it lead me down this big rabbit hole where I ended up using require.js and the text module, and a router, and two new js files (main and app), along with a view and a template. I'm currently getting an error in the view stating that Backbone cannot read property 'view' of undefined. This is my code:

In index.html, I include require.js, and make it reference main.js as the inital file:

then in main.js, I specify a template directory, and send it off to app.js:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    jquery: 'vendor/jquery/jquery-2.0.2.min',
    underscore: 'vendor/underscore/underscore-min',
    backbone: 'vendor/backbone/backbone-min',
    templates: '../templates'
  }
});

require([
  'app',
], function(App){
  App.initialize();
});
```

In app.js, I initialize the router:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'router', // Request router.js
], function($, _, Backbone, Router){
  var initialize = function(){
    // Pass in our Router module and call it's initialize function
    Router.initialize();
  };

  return {
    initialize: initialize
  };
});
```

and in router.js, I set up a route for my view:

```
// Filename: router.js
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'views/search/SearchFormView'
], function($, _, Backbone, SearchFormView) {

  var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      // Define some URL routes
      'search': 'SearchFormView'
    }
  });

  var initialize = function(){

    var app_router = new AppRouter;

    app_router.on('route:SearchFormView', function(){

        // Call render on the module we loaded in via the dependency array
        var searchView = new SearchFormView();
        searchView.render();

    });
    Backbone.history.start();
  };
  return {
    initialize: initialize
  };
});
```

Lastly, I just create that view, which will load my template:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'text!templates/search/search-form-template.html'

], function($, _, Backbone, searchFormTemplate){
  var SearchFormView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
        // Compile the template using underscore
        var template = _.template( $("#template-flight-match").html(), {} );
        // Load the compiled HTML into the Backbone "el"
        this.$el.html( template );
    }
  });
  return SearchFormView;
});
```

but it's not working, and I can't figure out why. Any help is much appreciated. Apologize for the excessive amount of code, but all of it seems to be necessary just to load this stuff the proper way.

Comment: did you step through the code to figure out where the execution fails using dev tools or firebug?

Comment: Having the line that actually triggers the error would help. Require is helpful for that.

Comment: The console lists the problem at this line: var SearchFormView = Backbone.View.extend({

Comment: I noticed that if I log Backbone in the view, it comes up as undefined. Why would that be?

Comment: are you using the AMD version of Backbone? knowing this is important if you are not using the AMd version you need to shim backbone in your app.ja file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment you actually have a problem with your config. Backbone is not an AMD module, so you have to use the [shim](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) option of `requirejs`. Well, the example speaks for itself as it's about Backbone.

Comment: and you post this as and answer just after I put it on a comment...ok

Comment: Sorry I took some time writing my answer as I was doing something else as the same time. Also sorry for posting an answer to his **actual** problem. You don't seem to understand how SO works. You don't put answer to say something completely irrelevant, and answer with a comment.

Comment: Ok, SO in your opinion works only for the reputation not for helping, I get it, Im voting your answer then. Great Job.

Comment: @Rayweb_on answering IS helping. Something that doesn't answer the problem in the question should be put in a comment as a side-note. Maybe you simply didn't read the problem before answering, otherwise you'd have known what you answered wasn't related to his error. And why great job? I found his problem, I answer, I don't see the problem. Well, good day to you sir.

Comment: Have to give it to Loamhoof as it was in the form of an answer, but thanks Rayweb nonetheless, I upvoted your answer - I switched to the AMD version of Backbone, but I really would like to understand shim a bit better, as I feel like this will be better maintained on future changes. If anyone posts some code that relates to my example, I'd love to see it, and would change the accepted answer.

Comment: @mheavers Im glad that switching to the AMD version worked, if you still have any doubt please ask a new question, this time will put it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

you have to use the template that you are requiring in this case, searchFormTemplate instead of trying to get it with jquery.

The text plugin will deliver you the right HTML and it will be enclosed in the variable searchFormTemplate so you can use it.

change this in yhe render function of your SearchFormeView

```
render: function(){
    // Compile the template using underscore
    var template = _.template(searchFormTemplate, {} ); // 
    // Load the compiled HTML into the Backbone "el"
    this.$el.html( template );
}
```

Comment: Don't you think it's just a typo? "*I'm currently getting an error in the view stating that Backbone cannot read property 'view' of undefined.*". Seems to me like there is no link to these 2 lines of code as they don't involve Backbone.

Comment: You're right about trying to apply this via jquery, however that didn't solve the problem. I think Loamhoof might be on the right track  with it being an error. The error in the console registers to this line: var SearchFormView = Backbone.View.extend({

Answer (score 0):

Install the text plugin which is available at https://github.com/requirejs/text

Then proceed to define the plugin in here:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    text: '{{directory where you put text.js}}',
  }
});
```

Since we are at this topic, requirejs-tpl-plugin is a better option https://github.com/jfparadis/requirejs-tpl

Comment: As stated to Rayweb_on, do you think it has any link to the error he's getting? Plus, why giving him a link to text.js while he's bviously already using it?

Comment: In his require.config example, he is not having the text plugin setting.